# Virtualbox unresponsive area on desktop

Tags: virtualbox

On Virtualbox running Ubuntu I've encountered several times bug where suddenly top left quarter of the desktop becomes unresponsive to mouse clicks, what is causing this and how could I fix this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This problem seems to be related to VBoxClient process being stuck, simply looking this from process list and ending the process seems to work as a fix.

For me killing instances ran with --draganddrop parameter restored the functionality of that area.

You can open terminal using keyboard combination of ctrl+alt+t, and type:

```
ps aux www | grep VBoxClient --
```

to look for the process ID (PID) 
then kill it with

```
kill -9 PID
```

Alternatively `pkill VBoxClient` might do the trick.

After this to restore drag and drop support you can run

```
VBoxClient-all
```

For reference here is xwininfo of the un-clickable area:

```
  xwininfo: Window id: 0x1200001 "VBoxClientWndDnD"

  Absolute upper-left X:  0
  Absolute upper-left Y:  0
  Relative upper-left X:  0
  Relative upper-left Y:  0
  Width: 800
  Height: 600
  Depth: 0
  Visual: 0x21
  Visual Class: TrueColor
  Border width: 0
  Class: InputOnly
  Colormap: 0x0 (not installed)
  Bit Gravity State: ForgetGravity
  Window Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
  Backing Store State: NotUseful
  Save Under State: no
  Map State: IsViewable
  Override Redirect State: yes
  Corners:  +0+0  -1120+0  -1120-375  +0-375
  -geometry 800x600+0+0
```

Comment: Thank you. For future reference, if anyone has a problem like this, start xprop from a virtual console, and then click on the un clickable area. It will output the name of the window, which in turn willl allow you to debug the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Can't comment on Allu2's answer, having the same problem with Ubuntu 18 while using Pycharm. Seems to be something with copying code chunks after an hour or two coding. Entire desktop area stops working, although Gnome's taskbars still work.

Use the following to pipe the --draganddrop processes to kill: 
`ps aux www |grep 'VBoxClient --draganddrop' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS while using Visual Studio Code. Allu2's answer was very helpfull.
(This is my first post, so I could not comment his answer directly)

Another way of going about restarting `VBoxClientWndDnD` is to disable **Drag and Drop** from the menu bar, then re-enable it.

[image]

Comment: Hello. This answer could be improved by having a correct version number. There is no version 20

Comment: Noted. Corrected OS Name

Answer (score 0):

This so weird but for me, I had web storm open. restarting it solve the problem. Note that i have tried saving the machine state and restarting vbox but that did not work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).